# Is this a synergistic interaction or antagonistic?

Tags: anova, interaction, interpretation, two-way

I ran a two-way ANOVA and I found this plot, but I am not sure the interaction I found is synergistic or antagonistic. Here, I have investigated effect of sex and three different location on fish length.[image]